# clojure destructure vector of vectors to return each vector

Tags: vector, clojure

I am very new to clojure and the syntax is pretty rough. I'm trying to destructure a vector of vectors.

This is the output from a function I use:
[[:b 2 3] [:b 3 7] [:b 9 8]]

But, what I would like it to do is display the output like so:
[:b 2 3] [:b 3 7] [:b 9 8]

Basically, trying to get rid of those out-most brackets.  Is this possible?  Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Are you happy with the function returning a vector of vectors?  When you say you want it to display without the outer-most brackets, do you mean that you want to "print" the vector of vectors to screen without the outer-most brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the specified output, you can certainly massage things that way:

```
(apply str (interpose " " [[:b 2 3] [:b 3 7] [:b 9 8]]))
;= "[:b 2 3] [:b 3 7] [:b 9 8]"
```

does the trick.  As for destructuring, if you had a function `f` which returned `[[:b 2 3] [:b 3 7] [:b 9 8]]`, you could use destructuring as follows:

```
(defn f []  ;; something presumably more complicated goes here
    [[:b 2 3] [:b 3 7] [:b 9 8]])

(let [[a b c] (f)]
    (println a b c))
; prints [:b 2 3] [:b 3 7] [:b 9 8]
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks so much for the feedback.  This did in fact work.  After a bit of research, I also discovered the root of my problem was that I was using (conj) in the function and not (concat).

Comment: `(apply str (interpose s coll))` is just `(clojure.string/join s coll)`.

Comment: No matter how compact my Clojure code, I always find there's a (in this case, slightly) more compact way to do it! :-)